# Can't push view controller after overriding openURL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to override my application's openURL method to intercept link clicks in a UITextView. The UITextView is in a a navigation based DetailViewController, and when the user clicks the link, I want to push a web view onto the navigation stack.

I verified that my method is being called by logging the intercepted url to the console, but the navigation controller is not pushing my WebViewController at all. I made a button in interface builder and added it onto the same view with the textview just to verify the WebView gets pushed. The button was just for testing purposes.

The problem seems that the navigationController pushViewController code isn't getting fired when I call the method from the AppDelegate, even though the NSLog shows I'm getting the valid intercepted url.

I appreciate any help offered! Code:

Inside AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    DetailViewController *webView = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

    webView.url = url;

    [webView push];

    return YES;
}
```

DetailViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

- (void)push;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)push
{
    WebViewController *webView = [[WebViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    webView.url = self.url;

    NSLog(@"%@",self.url);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: is `self.navigationController` nil when you are calling `pushViewController:animated:`?

Comment: It looks like it is, but I have no idea why, the NSLog confirms it: if(self.navigationController == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"uh-oh");
    }

Comment: Where are you creating your UINavigationController? If you alloc/init a UIViewController subclass it doesn't come with a navigation controller automatically.

Comment: In the app delegate, I'm using PKRevealController. I can push other detail views all day, but I can't get this WebView one to be pushed. As I said in the question, if I make a UIButton and wire the action to the method, the WebView does get pushed.

Comment: How can I access the DetailViewController's navigationController without alloc initing it in the AppDelegate? As I believe that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by using an NSNotification. Code below for others who find this:

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"WebViewNotification" object:url]];

    return YES;
}
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(webViewNotification:) name:@"WebViewNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)webViewNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSURL *url = [notification object];

    WebViewController *webView = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    webView.url = url;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webView animated:YES];
}
```