# Custom URL Handling iOS xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to set up my application so that I can add an NSUrl attribute to specified substrings of a textview, and when that NSUrl is touched, it pushes a new view rather than open a new url.

I am ovverriding OpenURL in my AppDelegate.cs class, and sending a notification with the url

```
public override bool OpenUrl (UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
{
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification (NSNotification.FromName ("ArtistDetail", url));

        return true;
}
```

Then in my class that contains the the text view, I add the observer in the constructor

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("ArtistDetail", delegate{artistDetail(null);});
```

And have my method

```
    public void artistDetail (NSNotification notification)
    {
        //push view based on info in notification.object
    }
```

I'm not having any luck. I found this article [Can't push view controller after overriding openURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325676/cant-push-view-controller-after-overriding-openurl) where someone did it in objective C the same way.  One problem - I'm putting breakpoints and log notes in my OpenURL override, and they're not getting hit.  When you click/tap an NSSUrl, does it by default call OpenUrl?  If so, why isn't my override getting hit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323338/ios7-uitextview-set-nslinkattributename-attribute-but-can-not-click

Comment: @JiaYow My question is not how to add the URL to the textview.  My question is how to dynamically handle the URL when it is touched

Comment: The question I linked has an answer that may explain why your OpenUrl is not called.

Comment: @JiaYow my link shows up and is clickable - it will even work as intended if the link is a regular hyperlink - However, it does not go through my overridden OpenUrl method.

Comment: what about your Xamarin version? I googled a bit and found this: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12306/openurl-not-being-called - maybe you're having the same problem?

Comment: I have figured it out - thanks for looking around for me @JiaYow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been researching how to do this for 6 hours.  Of course, 20 minutes after I post the question on SO, I figure out the answer.

I had to implement a UIApplication subclass, override the method there, register it, and launch it as the UIApplication in my Main.cs.

UIApplicationMain.cs

```
[Register ("UIApplicationMain")]
public class UIApplicationMain : UIApplication
{
    public UIApplicationMain ()
    {
    }

    public override bool OpenUrl (NSUrl url)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification (NSNotification.FromName ("ArtistDetail", url));

        return true;

    }
}
```

Main.cs

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main (args, "UIApplicationMain", "AppDelegate");
    }

}
```

View Controller where the hyperlinks are displayed, and should be handled dynamically to push the view controller you want

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("ArtistDetail", artistDetail);
}
public void artistDetail (NSNotification notification)
{
        NSUrl artistName = (NSUrl)notification.Object;

        String name = artistName.AbsoluteString;
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController (new ArtistDetailViewController (name), true);
 }
```

For anyone trying to solve the problem of "How to put a button within your UITextView" 
(like twitter does with #hastags and @users) - this is it! Put the text in an NSAttributedString, apply the link attribute to the text you want to act as a button, and handle accordingly.